# jquery new appended tr click can't work when dynamically create table using jquery one()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have table which dynamically created like following:

```
--Tier 1--

  --Tier 2--

    --Tier 3--

--Another Tier 1--
```

Tier 2 is created by clicking tier1, tier 3 is created by clicking tier2. Now tier 3 can't be created when click tier 2. All creation could be executed only once.
My Js code:

```
 $('tbody>tr:has(td)').one('click', function() {
     //some code;
     }
 });
```

My html code:

```
<tbody>
    <tr class="clickable level_0" data-toggle="collapse" id="row0" data-target=".row0"></tr>
    <tr class="clickable row0 level_1 collapse in" data-toggle="collapse" id="row00" data-target=".row00" aria-expanded="true"></tr>
    <tr class="clickable row0 level_1 collapse in" data-toggle="collapse" id="row01" data-target=".row01" aria-expanded="true"></tr>
    <tr class="clickable level_0" data-toggle="collapse" id="row1" data-target=".row1"></tr>
</tbody>
```

How could tier3 will be created when click tier2 at the first time? Thanks everyone.

Comment: you need event delegation for dynamically created elements

Comment: Thanks your timely response. I tried to use on() function, like $('tbody).on('click', 'tr', function(){}), but that will append multiple same tier, i just want to create once.In another word, i want use on() and one() together. @guradio

Comment: what you can do is have a condition set to true then set to false inside so it wont fire again.

Comment: @xiaxiaochan - so you need to set a flag to make sure your code only runs once. Check out my solution below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're creating your `<td>` elements dynamically, the javascript code you used will not work(since those elements are not yet created) & you need to use "event delegation".

```
$('tbody').on('click', 'tr:has(td)', function() {
   if($(this).data('clicked')) {
     return;
   }

   //some code;

   $(this).data('clicked', true);
});
```

**Explanation:**

Instead of binding the "click" event handler directly to the dynamically creating element(`td`), you can instead bind it to a parent element(`tbody` or `table` or a container `div`) & **watch for a change/addition of new child elements**. Also for delegating `.on` event only once, you could create a flag(`clicked`) which can be made `true` after the first iteration so it will not run your code again the next time. Technically your code will be called all the time but will run only once (same as `.one` event).

> Read more about delegation from [here](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

Comment: Thanks! it works and is better than my solution. i also resolved it just now by check next tr class of current tr. Thanks for your timely response.@Nanjappa.

Comment: No problem, glad it helped.

Answer (score 0):

Change the code like this (Event delegation for dynamic elements) and its working like as one().

```
 $('table').on('click', 'tbody>tr:has(td)', function(event) {
     //some code;

     $(this).off(event); // last line
 });
```

Comment: If off the click, the function will be execute only once. but i want every tier be created at the first click.@Karthik